# How can I display my Excel file in Arcmap 10.4?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel, table, attribute-joins

I am currently working on a project. I have created an excel spreadsheet: [image: States Population]

So, I need to attach the spreadsheet into ArcMap 10.4 and show the states population percentage. I have already created a floating layer. I know that I need to join the two layers, but I am not sure what to base the join on. At first I did it based on state name and nothing happen. So, I need help joining the layers and I also need help projecting what is on my spreadsheet onto arcmap once the join is done.

Do I join or relate?

Comment: Are you sure the same naming you have in excel exist in floating layer ?

Comment: Hi Shady, No I wasn't using the same name and I also had space issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have GIS data, for example (State Boundary), in Arcmap in order to visualize the excel population data in GIS. The state boundary should have a field of StateName or State_Name that the names of the states in this field should be exactly similar to the names of the states in the State Name field in Excel. Otherwise, there will be no join relation between the GIS data and Excel data.

Another option is that you can add common ID (in ID Field) in both excel file and the feature file (state boundary) that you can use it as a base to join your population data.

Comment: Hi Ahmadhanb, Thank you! Now, if I base the join on state_name, is there a way to show all the states population in each year and the total_pop_population or do I have to do that separately, like I can only show total_pop_percentage for all the states?

Comment: If you base the join on state_name, you will join the whole excel table from POP_1950 to Total Population Percentage. Be careful that a field's name must be no more than 10 characters in length; additional characters will be truncated. You need to adjust the excel field names especially "Total Population Percentage" to be within 10 characters.

Comment: okay, so I just modified my total_pop_population to Totalpop. I was able to import the excel and join the table. What I am having trouble doing is coming up with a query to show the different populations in each state for each year and also showing the total population. I was thinking that I could come up with one whole query and do a graduated color map or create a different layer for each year?

Comment: You can export the joined feature with the excel file into a new shapefile to make it permanent. Then you can do the query, but this will be another question. So if the joined process solved your problem to display the excel file into ArcMap, then please accept the answer so others will know that it has been resolved.

Comment: There is a green mark under the voting, just check that, and it will appear accepted. You check the tour http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Sorry about that I think I just accepted your answer. Can I continue asking you questions or should I ask a new question?

Comment: You have to ask a new clear question with details and illustrations, if you can, so everyone can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you'll need a spatial layer showing the state boundaries. A rough dataset is included with ArcGIS and is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb (or a similar path on your computer).

You'll need to make some changes to your Excel file before you add it to ArcMap. Note that the column names cannot have spaces, so you should rename *State Name* to *State_name* or similar. Same with *Total Pop Percentage*.

Note that the state names must match exactly in order for the join to work, so may need to change the capitalized state names to Proper case. In Excel use the formula `=PROPER(A2)` to convert *OHIO* to *Ohio*.

Now add the Excel file to ArcMap and join the States layer with the Excel file.

Comment: Thank you! Now, if I base the join on state_name, is there a way to show all the states population in each year and the total_pop_population or do I have to do that separately, like I can only show total_pop_percentage for all the states?

Comment: I'm glad you resolved the first question. You should ask a brand new question for further enquriies, to help keep Stack Exchange a simple _one question plus its answers_ site